# Change value based on frequency in a column in given dataframe_Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, apply

I have dataset containing 180000 wind speed which are discrete ranging from 0 to 30. I want to change those discrete integer values to specified decimals based on the frequencies.

So, I need a code that searches for wind speed==i (i is integer ranging from 0 to 30) and replaces the first n1 (given by frequency) by a new value, next n2 by another value, and so on.
It should do this for all wind speeds.

Input:

1. Dataframe with one column containing wind speed ranging from 0 to 30 (unsorted).
2. Frequency [0,1820,2459,2745,2925,....]
   Frequency is such that it's split into 5 of a segment. Meaning for each integer wind speed, it is to be replaced by new dataset based on frequency.
   Ex: 0 to be replaced by 0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8. The number of occurence depend on frequency.
   1 to be replaced by 1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8 and so on
3. New dataset=[0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1.2,...]
   So, for wind speed==0, it should replace first 1820 (occurence of 0) by 0.2, next 2459 occurence by 0.4, next 2745 by 0.6, and final 2925 by 0.8.
   For new dataset 1 to 1.8, replace wind speed==1 based on frequency specified.
   For wind speed==1, it should take new dataset value>1. See attached image for further clarity.

Output:
Discrete wind speed integer 0 to 30 replaced by 0.2,0.4,... (0.2 increment) based on frequency.

Note: The dataframe is unsorted and I would like to keep it that way.

[Dataset sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLnKW.png)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It may not be very efficient in terms of computation, however it does the work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
speeds=[0]*5 + [1]*5 + [2]*5 + [3]*5 + [4]*5 + [5]*5 

#update the frequency with the actual frequencies
df=pd.DataFrame({'Speed': speeds ,  'v':np.r_[0:30]*0,
                'frequency': ([0, 1820, 2459, 2745, 2925] + [1]*25)})
                
#Need to update the keys of the dictionary below accordingly

dict={0: {0:0, 1820:0.2, 2459:0.4, 2745:0.6, 2925:0.8  },
      1: {5:1.0, 6:1.2, 7:1.4, 8:1.6, 9:1.8 }
}

for key1 in dict:
    for key2 in dict[key1].keys():
        df.loc[ (df['Speed']==key1) & (df['frequency']==key2), 'v']= dict[key1][key2]
        
print(df)
```